# Best practice - REST API response decoded as array or object on client side

Tags: php, json, rest

I have the following issue:

I make a call to a rest api. It returns a json with data. Now I need on client to process that data and do something with it (doesn't really matter what).

I can either decode the json as an object, or as an associative array. Are there any good practices saying that I should go one way or another (with solid reasons behind them)?

Personally I'm inclined towards object, but in some cases this may not be the best choice (for example when there is a numerical indexed array encoded in json, it will be decoded as array inside the object, so I'm ending up with two types of data - is not a big problem, but is a bit inconvenient).

Comment: _"primarily opinion-based
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON/<strike>Javascript</strike>ECMAScript clearly delineates between *objects* and *arrays* (as do many other languages, which call them lists and dictionaries, or hashes, or whatever). Objects are unordered key-value pairs, while arrays are ordered numerically indexed containers.

PHP doesn't make that distinction in its arrays, PHP's arrays are ordered key-value pairs also allowing numeric keys. But PHP *also* happens to have a concept of *objects*. `json_decode` simply offers you which way you want to map those ambiguous data types. It's entirely up to you.

There's not a lot you can do with `stdClass` objects, while arrays are very flexible data structures with tons of manipulation functions. Take your pick. It largely doesn't matter.